# Mirroring a string

Tags: linux, string, bash, unix, mirror

How can I mirror a string?
If found this: `echo $("123" | rev)`. This works fine. But when I put it in a variable, it doesn't display anything:

```
output=$("123" | rev)
echo $output
```

How can I get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed that for you:

```
output $(echo -n "123" | rev)
echo $output
```

If its in a subshell, make sure `output` is not local, *and* export it explicitely:

```
function bla()
{
    output=$(echo -n "123" | rev)
    export output
}

bla    
echo $output
```

Next time, you might want to mention more relevant context in your question :)

Comment: Doesn't output anything :(. It's inside a function:
`# Create a user
create_user() {
 check_user $1
        output = $(echo -n "123" | rev)
 echo $output
}`, but after executing, it's empty.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the lack of context ;p. One last question: I want to keep it local. But this isn't working :(: `create_user() {
 check_user $1
    local output = $(echo -n "123" | rev)
 echo $output
}` Can you help me one more time?? ;)

Comment: Spacing was the keyword xD. Why is `locvar = blaat` not equal to `locvar=blaat`? Weird...

Comment: The pedantic answer would have to be 'because it contains more spaces'; Slightly less pedantic: 'because `a=b` means assignment, and `a = b` means call _program or function_ `a` with two parameters'